# How to operate on all unique instances of elements in an array without looping?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Say I have a matrix `A` whose first column contains item ID and second column contains its weight.

```
3   2
2   1
2   4
1   7
3   4
2   5
1   2
4   3
2   5
3   6
```

I want to find the average weight of each item. So, the following is the output I want:

```
1   4.5
2   3.75
3   4
4   3
```

The code I would write to do this is the following:

```
items = unique(A(:,1));
for i=1:size(A,1)
    temp=A(A(:,1)==items(i,1),:);
    items(i,2)=mean(temp(:,2));
end
```

Here, `items` is the required output. However, as the number of instances of each item increases, as well as the dataset size increases, this code performs poorly in terms of speed, as it has to first collect all instances of a unique items and then calculate the average weight.

Is there a way to do this without having to loop through the dataset again and again collecting all instances of each unique item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what [**`accumarray`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). is for:

```
out = accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,2),[],@mean)
```

---

```
out =

    4.5000
    3.7500
    4.0000
    3.0000
```

---

This short solution requires the IDs to be integers, if that's not the case, you can use the more general approach using [**`unique`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
[~,~,subs] = unique(A(:,1))
vals = A(:,2);
out = accumarray(subs(:),vals(:),[],@mean)
```

Comment: I bet you have a google alert for it or something :p

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works in this example dataset. But when I apply it in my real dataset, I get the following error: `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` Would you know why that might be?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Not really ;) But its a very useful function one should always keep in mind!

Comment: @there could are various reasons, especially the actual orientation of your data. Please share parts or your datasets.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Never mind :-) Your second code worked! I guess the more general code needs to be applied not only when the IDs are non-integers, but even when the weights are non-integers.

Comment: @Kristada673 no actually not. But the second approach is much more robust, that's true.

Comment: @thewaywewalk What if the second column has binary data, and as output, say I want the ratio of the number of 0s to 1s for each ID. Could you kindly tell me how to do that using `accumarray`? I was thinking of making a custom function called `ratio` and use that in `accumarray`, but implementing that function too requires looping for each ID.

Comment: @Kristada673 I don't see the difference between ratio and mean for binary data? `a = [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]` -> `mean(a) = 0.6250` the same as `5/8`. If you want the reverse value, you could do `out = accumarray(subs(:),vals(:),[],@(x) 1-mean(x))`

Comment: @thewaywewalk No, I mean, now suppose as output, I don't want the mean, but I want the ratio of number of 0s to 1s. Then how to do that?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Oh, I didn't think of that! Now I feel stupid.

Comment: @thewaywewalk How about in this situation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392152/is-there-a-way-to-quickly-evaluate-the-ratio-of-cluster-sizes-in-k-means-cluster

Comment: @Kristada673 I'm not your personal support. Please post a new question.

Comment: @thewaywewalk That WAS a new question I posted.

Comment: @Kristada673 ah sorry :) nevermind! I haven't noted that. I'm not familiar with that further topic, so I can't help you. Sorry